# Advanced logic books recommendations

Tags: logic, reference-request

I've studied from  introduction to logic by Harry Jensler, so I'm looking for a more advanced and profound logic books any recommendations will be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: De Swart, Philosophical and Mathematical Logic https://www.abebooks.fr/9783030032531/Philosophical-Mathematical-Logic-Harrie-Swart-3030032531/plp

Comment: See Peter Smith's guide ( author's website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent, it depends on what you are looking for. If you want to progress beyond first order predicate logic, you might want to consider:

Hughes and Cresswell, A New Introduction to Modal Logic

- this is a standard text on modal logic

Graham Priest, An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic

- probably the best introduction to logics outside the family of classical logics

George Boolos, John Burgess, Richard Jeffrey, Computability and Logic

- a good introduction to computability theory and its relation to logic

Jonathan Bennett, Conditionals: A Philosophical Guide;

David Sanford, If P then Q

- two of the better introductory books on the logic of conditionals

Anthony Grayling, An Introduction to Philosophical Logic

- a good introduction to some of the philosophical concepts around logic

Susan Haack, Philosophy of Logics;

John Etchemendy, The Concept of Logical Consequence;

W V Quine, Philosophy of Logic;

Penelope Rush, The Metaphysics of Logic;

Matthew McKeown, The Concept of Logical Consequence

- books on the philosophy of logic

Answer (score 0):

"Introduction to logic" Alfred Tarski

"Metalogic: An introduction to the Metatheory of Standard First Order Logic" Goeffrey Hunter

"Tractatus logico-philosophicus" Ludwig Wittgenstein

"Philosophy of logic" W.V. Quine

"The mathematical analysis of logic" George Boole